# Seperate String into parts and validate them

Tags: shell

I'm writing a shell script and I have the string:

```
2 00:03 2 01:03 2 02:03 2 03:03 2 04:03 2 05:03 2 06:03 2 07:03 2 08:03 2 09:03 2 10:03 2 11:03 2 12:03 2 23:03
```

the leading 2 is the count of the timestamp following. Now I have to validate that each timestamp is counted exact 2 times.

At the end i want an ok or wrong as outcome.

Can't find a solution on myself to seperate the string or do whatever to check it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the desired output?

Comment: `validate the each timestamp is exact 2 time in the string` - validate two times what occurs?

Comment: the desired output is either ok or wrong depending on, if every timestamp has a 2 in front of it

Comment: please edit you Q to show the exact output you expect from your given input (which doesn't really align with your verbal description of "the leading 2 is the count of the timestamp following. (IMHO) ). ..... Is that series of data really on one line? And do we really need >80 chars of sample data to understand the problem?, reduce the size of your problem description my friend ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A bash-specific solution:

```
validate () ( # executing function in a subshell
    set -f
    set -- $1
    local -i n=$1
    shift 2
    while (( $# > 0 )); do 
        (( $1 == n )) || return 1
        shift 2
    done
)
```

Then, we can do

```
$ s="2 00:03 2 01:03 2 02:03 2 03:03 2 04:03 2 05:03 2 06:03 2 07:03 2 08:03 2 09:03 2 10:03 2 11:03 2 12:03 2 23:03"

$ if validate "$s"; then echo OK; else echo bad; fi
OK

$ if validate "1 foo 2 bar"; then echo OK; else echo bad; fi
bad
```